# Can I write a geometric series expansion like this?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$1+x+x^2 + O(x^3)$

and if it alternates,

$1-x+x^2 + O(x^3)$,

so that whether the geometric series alternates or not, the remainder term goes to zero like $x^3$.

(The alternating series confuses me a little bit.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. In the geometric series, the powers of $x $ increase without bound, so how could you employ big-O of $x^3$?

Comment: The geometric sum is not defined unless $|x|<1$, so of course we cannot interpret the big O notation as $x\to\infty$. Rather, the big O notation applies here on the interpretation $x\to0$. The meaning of the statement $f(x)=g(x)+O(h(x))$ as $x\to a$ is that $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is bounded by a constant multiple of $|h(x)|$ in some neighborhood of $a$. You can even make sense of this statement if $a=\infty$ if one correctly interprets "neighborhood of infinity."

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})+x^n(1+x+\cdots) $$

$$=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}+x^n(1-x)^{-1}$$

and $(1-x)^{-1}$ is bounded in any neighborhood of $0$ within $(-1,1)$, we can say (as $x\to0$)

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}+O(x^n).$$

You can just replace $x$ with $-x$ above to get the alternating version.